# How to make the rows of a data.frame into individual unique data.frames

Tags: r

I have a data.frame that has a bunch of rows with unique IDs followed by an amino acid sequence. I was wondering if there was a way to split up the rows into individual unique data.frame.

Here is an example

bigdf

```
>ENSCAFP00000018847.4  
FGHFGHFGHFGHFHFGHFGHFGHFGHFHFGHFGHFHFGHFGHFHFHFHFGTNSEGAFQTA
DLLETSVPSHMPLETQTLSPQTFDWTLILANSNSEAETRDTKTTFPAMEGRAFTKMTPSK
>ENSCAFP00000018847.3  
VCXVNSFRERYTRIOUHFSDAADSSAASAAAAGPVVTANHVEEPAMTPGVRTNSEGAFQTA
DLLETSVPSHMPLETQTLSPQTFDWTLILANSNSEAETRDTKTTFPAMEGRAFTKMTPSK
>ENSCAFP00000018847.2  
ASDASDADASDASDASDASDASSADASASRPGPVVTANHVEEPAMTPGVRTNSEGAFQTA
DLLETSVPSHMPLETQTLSPQTFDWTLILANSNSEAETRDTKTTFPAMEGRAFTKMTPSK
>ENSCAFP00000018847.1  
QWEQWEQWEQWEWQREWRQWEQWRQRQQRERPGPVVTANHVEEPAMTPGVRTNSEGAFQTA
DLLETSVPSHMPLETQTLSPQTFDWTLILANSNSEAETRDTKTTFPAMEGRAFTKMTPSK
```

It would be nice if I could have the name of the new data.frames be their IDs so hopefully the results could look like this

ENSCAFP00000018847.4

```
>ENSCAFP00000018847.4  
FGHFGHFGHFGHFHFGHFGHFGHFGHFHFGHFGHFHFGHFGHFHFHFHFGTNSEGAFQTA
DLLETSVPSHMPLETQTLSPQTFDWTLILANSNSEAETRDTKTTFPAMEGRAFTKMTPSK
```

ENSCAFP00000018847.3

```
>ENSCAFP00000018847.3  
VCXVNSFRERYTRIOUHFSDAADSSAASAAAAGPVVTANHVEEPAMTPGVRTNSEGAFQTA
DLLETSVPSHMPLETQTLSPQTFDWTLILANSNSEAETRDTKTTFPAMEGRAFTKMTPSK
```

ENSCAFP00000018847.2

```
>ENSCAFP00000018847.2  
ASDASDADASDASDASDASDASSADASASRPGPVVTANHVEEPAMTPGVRTNSEGAFQTA
DLLETSVPSHMPLETQTLSPQTFDWTLILANSNSEAETRDTKTTFPAMEGRAFTKMTPSK
```

ENSCAFP00000018847.1

```
>ENSCAFP00000018847.1 QWEQWEQWEQWEWQREWRQWEQWRQRQQRERPGPVVTANHVEEPAMTPGVRTNSEGAFQTADLLETSVPSHMPLETQTLSPQTFDWTLILANSNSEAETRDTKTTFPAMEGRAFTKMTPSK
```

I know this should like a strange thing to do but need to do this for thousands of different amino acid sequences so it would be cool if I could find a way to split them all up in R

```
dput(df[1:3, c(1)])
c("> ENSCAFP00000018847.4 MFFINIISLIIPILLAVAFLTLVERKVLGYMQLRKGPNIVGPYGLLQPIADAVKLFTKEPLRPLTSSMSMFILAPILALSLALTMWIPLPMPYPLINMNLGVLFMLAMSSLAVYSILWSGWASNSKYALIGALRAVAQTISYEVTLAIILLSVLLMNGSFTLSTLIITQEHMWLIFPAWPLAMMWFISTLAETNRAPFDLTEGESELVSGFNVEYAAGPFALFFLAEYANIIMMNILTTILFFGAFHNPFMPELYSINFTMKTLLLTICFLWIRASYPRFRYDQLMHLLWKNFLPLTLALCMWHVALPIITASIPPQT", 
"> ENSCAFP00000018847.3 MKPPILIIIMATIMTGTMIVMLSSHWLLIWIGFEMNMLAIIPILMKKYNPRAMEASTKYFLTQATASMLLMMGVTINLLYSGQWVISKISNPIASIMMTTALTMKLGLSPFHFWVPEVTQGITLMSGMILLTWQKIAPMSILYQISPSINTNLLMLMALTSVLVGGWGGLNQTQLRKIMAYSSIAHMGWMAAIITYNPTMMVLNLTLYILMTLSTFMLFMLNSSTTTLSLSHMWNKFPLITSMILILMLSLGGLPPLSGFIPKWMIIQELTKNNMIIIPTLMAITALLNLYFYLRLTYSTALTMFPSTNNMKMKWQFEYTKKATLLPPLIITSTMLLPLTPMLSVLD", 
"> ENSCAFP00000018847.2 MFINRWLFSTNHKDIGTLYLLFGAWAGMVGTALSLLIRAELGQPGTLLGDDQIYNVIVTAHAFVMIFFMVMPIMIGGFGNWLVPLMIGAPDMAFPRMNNMSFWLLPPSFLLLLASSMVEAGAGTGWTVYPPLAGNLAHAGASVDLTIFSLHLAGVSSILGAINFITTIINMKPPAMSQYQTPLFVWSVLITAVLLLLSLPVLAAGITMLLTDRNLNTTFFDPAGGGDPILYQHLFWFFGHPEVYILILPGFGMISHIVTYYSGKKEPFGYMGMVWAMMSIGFLGFIVWAHHMFTVGMDVDTRAYFTSATMIIAIPTGVKVFSWLATLHGGNIKWSPAMLWALGFIFLFTVGGLTGIVLANSSLDIVLHDTYYVVAHFHYVLSMGAVFAIMGGFAHWFPLFSGYTLNDTWAKIHFTIMFVGVNMTFFPQHFLGLSGMPRRYSDYPDAYTTWNTVSSMGSFISLTAVMLMIFMIWEAFASKREVAMVELTTTNIEWLHGCPPPYHTFEEPTYVIQK"
)
```

Comment: Does `bigdf` only have one column? Are the two rows after the ID meant to be a continuous string of characters or two strings?

Comment: that is correct, it only has one column. It is one continuous string

Comment: Are you against keeping them all in one data frame with an ID column and a sequence column? It's a lot neater than a load of different data frames.

Comment: You can share few sample rows with `dput`? A better way is what @Lyngbakr suggested,

Comment: @Lyngbakr I, unfortunately, need them in their own data frame. The downstream software that I am going to use needs them like this

Comment: @Sonny I tried my best to put the dput output. Sorry I am a bit new

Comment: Your `dput` only shared one column. Are there other columns we need to worry about, or you just want this one column vector turned into multiple data frames?

Comment: @Gregor it is just one column! Sorry, I didn't make that clear

Comment: @Lyngbakr just to make it clear, the example about is just three rows. There is just one column. Each row contains a lot of data so I can see why that is confusing. Sorry I didn't think about these things with the original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put all the lines in a named list of data frames and then use `list2env()` to put them in the global environment like this:

`dfs <- apply(bigdf, MARGIN = 1, as.data.frame)
 names(dfs) <- str_sub(bigdf[,1], start = 1, end = 20)
 list2env(dfs, envir = .GlobalEnv)`

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the `apply` function and `as.data.frame` across the rows:

```
mydfs <- apply(df, 1, as.data.frame)
```

mydfs will be a list of the rows as individual dataframes.  Note they will be coerced.